# Pagespeed and GtMatrix trying to search since long but able to get resolved

Tags: wordpress, vps, pagespeed-insights

i am facing issue when i try to check or use any google tools (GTmatrix, PageSpeed Insights, Google Structure Data) to test my website. I got error

> The page took too long to load

But when i test the same website on other tools like Pingdom Tools it showing good result, Result of last test (Page Load Time 1.5 Sec, performance A Grade, Request 24, Page size 1.3 MB).

I have VPS CentOS7, with Apache.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when your website scripts/plugins takes forever before the page is ready to be served. Try following:

1. Add cache plugin(this will help in serving the page faster), or
2. Disable scripts/plugins, test and verify which plugin is causing the issue. or
3. Try serving a static page e.g. test.html and check if you get result for the page. If you indeed get pagespeed result than something is wrong with your website scripts/plugins.

Edit #1
A 15 second timeout has been introduced when considering the start of the page load. If your page doesn’t paint any content within ~15 seconds, Lighthouse will bail. This will result in the NO_FCP error.

Comment: Thankyou for the response, i am using Light Speed server, and Caching with LS Cache, as well as tried to disable all plugins, but still facing issues.

When I run this command 
' curl -D- localhost | less '

i got error 

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

and once i read that website is not detected as HTML i forget to take screenshot at that time and really dont know where i read that report

Comment: Please provide url of the website that has static page mentioned in point 3 so that I check.

Comment: Here is the Url : somivendors.com

Comment: I have updated the answer, after seeing your website it looks like it is exceeding the 15 second limit set by pagespeed. After that lighthouse will return the error which you saw on pagespeed. Test point 3 with simple page and check if you get pagespeed result.

Answer (score 0):

PageSpeed result is based on the combination of both real-world data and lab data. Some of the users may access your webpage from slow network or with old mobile devices. What you see is the average of the last 28 ​days. So even if you have taken improvement as James suggested, it takes time to see the change.

Pingdom free webpage speed test does not have option on devices and network(3G/4G). I guess it tests from desktop devices.

Comment: Thanks for response, i already took the steps suggested by James

Comment: This is not correct, the score is purely from lab data, the origin summary and page summary are based on real world data. So if you fix an issue and run lighthouse your score will improve instantly.

Comment: See [the difference between PageSpeed and lighhouse](https://www.optasy.com/blog/google-pagespeed-vs-lighthouse-how-are-they-different-and-which-tool-should-you-use)

Comment: That article is incorrect I am afraid. Perhaps read the [official Page Speed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/about#score) documentation as that is accurate. The important bit: "At the top of the report, PSI provides a score which summarizes the page’s performance. This **score is determined by running Lighthouse** to collect and analyze **lab data** about the page."

Comment: This article has the complete coverage of data source, metrics, etc.. You may have a test of a real url in [PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/). Note: if the tested url has little traffic, only lab data is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible causes of this after running a performance trace:-

### Highly Likely - Total Blocking Time (TBT) cannot be calculated

Lighthouse (the engine behind Page Speed Insights) never completes the Total Blocking Time test. For some reason you have a task that is permanently blocking the main thread, it appears to be something to do with animation so I would suggest removing the slider temporarily and then re running the test.

For Lighthouse to complete it needs a gap where the CPU is not busy to calculate TBT, as this gap never comes it cannot complete and errors.

### Less likely - request never completes

You have a request that never completes but also doesn't through an error:- https://somivendors.com/cdn-cgi/rum?req_id=65e9be0aae4e542e, yet again this could be causing Lighthouse to fail as it never gets to a fully loaded state. I find this less likely to be the cause as it is only a ping but as it never resolves it could be causing a time out.

Option 1 is where I would look (the slider or something to do with animation). I would also suggest you run a performance trace yourself and read how to interpret the results as you may be able to spot the problem more quickly as you know your code base (and can spend more time looking into it).